# Can I use a 3.5 mm to 3 rca cable?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a driver that I can install that would allow me to receive and send video signal through my headphone port on my PC using a 3.5 mm to 3 RCA cable?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please explain: why would you want to do that? Your audio card can only output audio through that port, so there's no way to make it send or even receive video.

Comment: I have the cable and so I was trying it out but my driver does not support video output nor input. So I was wondering if I can install a driver specifically for that so I can record video and audio straight from my camera to my PC

Comment: While we're at it I'm looking for a way to transmit 1Gbit/s from my router to my PC using a power cord. Which driver do I need? (My point being: You can not transmit **video** signals from your **audio** hard. This is simply a hardware "issue" and no driver can change the physical chipset of your computer.)

Comment: Okay, so it is not advisable to change my audio card nor I cant add on one either

Comment: I'll have to use my USB to RCA

Comment: Even if you tried to do this with some custom low-level program, I think it wouldn't work. Good audio cards are designed to process frequencies up to about 100 kHz, while poor old NTSC or PAL video signal requires like 4 MHz. I don't know voltage requirements. The cable is designed to work with compatible video equipment, not generic audio hardware.

Comment: @davidwhyte Your audiocard? There is no audiocard that can output video. That's what a graphics card is for. What exactly are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's a cool thought. Using really old analog displays and some special hardware (most likely has to be custom-made) it might be possible to make something that converts audio signals coming from the PC into a usable RCA signal. However I doubt one can get a decent resolution/FPS combination out of that. Also: why?

Comment: My audio card is Conexant. I was look to use my camera directly to my computer and the 3.5 mm to RCA is a bit more convenient for me

Comment: I was avoiding buying a new cable

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure about what you're saying. I own a few devices that output video over 3.5mm just fine?

Comment: @davidwhyte You can not use any audio card to receive an image from your camera. Not any. It's simply not possible. Your best bet is a RCA to USB capture card. They're cheap (~$10 on eBay)

Comment: My computer does not receive the video signal

Comment: @davidwhyte That's because your **audio** card doesn't know what to do with a video signal. The hardware in it wasn't made to receive video signals and software can't change that. That is like expecting a garden hose to transmit HDMI signals. Even with [this](http://www.schleckysilberstein.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/BjlTJzcCEAAmX0U.jpg) adapter, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase a video capture device such as [these](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_16?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=video%20capture%20usb&sprefix=video%20capture%20us%2Caps%2C143&crid=2HJNF6CZ0PAOG).  This will allow you to record video from an external device to a file on your computer.